# Kinetic JS Text Bending in 'middle'

Tags: kineticjs

I want to bend a line of Kinetic Text in Half. It's working, but the 'bend' is not happening in the 'center'. I'm trying to understand 'Why'.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/6gnTm/4/

I thought that if I dynamically positioned the points in that path, to match the width of the text, that I would get a 'rainbow' effect visually, an arc with both edges of the text lined up on the bottom.

there are 3 points in the text curve: 'start', 'control' and 'end'
The Horizontal Offset (offX) is half the width of the text object.

```
var lastWidth = (textpath.getTextWidth());
var offX = lastWidth / 2;
q.start.x = q.control.x - offX;
q.end.x = q.control.x + offX;
```

Is there a reason this isn't working?
ie: is the 'textWidth()' actually the length of the Arc of the text path, and not the horizontal width?

NOTE actually now that I've updated my control points to move accurately, I think I see the issue...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK so it works as long as I pull the left and right control points in toward the center to compensate... much better ...

```
    q.start.x = q.control.x - offX +( variation / 2);
    q.end.x = q.control.x + offX - ( variation / 2);
```

WORKING DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/6gnTm/5/